# Sticky Navbar, scroll to first element not precise

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, navbar

I'm trying to make an Navbar that sticks to top after scrolling to the first element(nav) e.g. 'News'. It works imprecise by hitting the 'news'. It scroll to much downwards, after hitting the 'News' again it scroll back up again to the right position. Curiously it only happen on the first element of the navBar.  How can i fix this?

```js
//Sticky-NavBar
window.onscroll = function() {stickyNavBar()};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function stickyNavBar() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/*Base*/
.contentBody{
  background-color: white;
}

/*Sections*/
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#header{}
#news{}
#products{background-color: aqua;}
#services{}
#customers{}
#community{}
#contact{}
#about{}
#footer{}
/*Width Element*/
.fitWidth{
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
.width100{
  width: 100%;
}
.fitContBoxLeft{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.fitContBoxRight{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
/**/


/*Borders*/
.roundedBorader{
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.roundedBox{
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
/*Div*/
.headingBox{
  position: relative
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 268;
}
.news{
  background-color: purple;
}
.products{
  background-color: white;
}
.services{
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.customers{
  background-color: blue;
}
.pBox1{
  float:left;
  width: 24.7%;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.headBottomLine{
  height: 12%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.leftBox50{
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 2px;
}
.rightBox50{
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 2px;
}
.bodyBox{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.aboutUs{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
.footerBox{
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

/*Backgrounds*/
.headBG{
  background-image: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/double-bubble.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

/*Position*/
.bottom0{
  bottom: 0;
}
.posRel{
  position: relative;
}
.posAbs{
  position: absolute;
}

/*Float*/
.floatLeft{
  float: left;
}
.floatRight{
  float: right;
}

/*Alignment*/
.justiText{
  text-align: justify;
}
.rightText{
  text-align: right;
}
.leftText{
  text-align: left;
}
.centerText{
  text-align: center;
}
.alignBox{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/*Padding*/
.pAll-5{
  padding: 5%;
}
.pTop-8{
  padding-top: 8%;
}
.pTop-5{
  padding-top: 5%;
}
.pTop-2{
  padding-top: 2%;
}
.mTop-n3{
  margin-top: -3%;
}
.mTop-5{
  margin-top: auto;
}
.mTop-6{
  margin-top: 6%;
}
.pLine{
  width:100%;
}
.pLR{
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.pBot-12{
  padding-bottom: 12%;
}
.pTop-10{
  padding-top: 10%;
}
.pTop-6{
    padding-top: 6%;
}
.pTop-1{
  padding-top: 2%;
}
.pLeft-30{
  padding-left: 30%;
}
.pLeft-25{
  padding-left: 25%;
}
.pLeft-20{
  padding-left: 20%;
}
.pLeft-10{
  padding-left: 10%;
}
.pLeft-5{
  padding-left: 5%;
}
.pRight-5{
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.pTop-4{
  padding-top: 4%;
}
.pAll-20{
  padding: 20px;
}
.pLTRB{
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.centerHeadLine{
    padding-bottom: 7%;
}

/*Colors*/
.white{
  color: white;
}
.black{
  color: black;
}
.grey{
  color: grey;
}
.lightgrey{
  color: lightgrey;
}
div.c{
  color: lightgrey;
}
div.b{
  color: white;
}
div.a{
  color: black;
}
.bgCol-black{
  background-color: black;
}
.bgCol-grey{
  background-color: grey;
}
.bgCol-purple{
  background-color: #8e42c7;
}
.bgCol-white{
  background-color: white;
}
.bgCol-lightgrey{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.bgCol-limegreen{
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.bgLightGreyX{
  background-color: #d5d2d670;
}

/*Filter styles*/
.saturate { filter: saturate(3); }
.grayscale { filter: grayscale(100%); }
.contrast { filter: contrast(160%); }
.brightness { filter: brightness(0.25); }
.blur { filter: blur(3px); }
.invert { filter: invert(100%); }
.sepia { filter: sepia(100%); }
.huerotate { filter: hue-rotate(180deg); }
.rss.opacity { filter: opacity(50%); }

/*Heading Colors*/
h1.a{
  color: white;
}
h1.b{
  color: black;
}
h5.a{
  color: white;
}
h4.b{
  color: black;
}
h4.a{
  color: white;
}
h5.b{
  color: black;
}

/*Body*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/*NavBar*/
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Nav-Dropdown*/
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #ea8013;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #333;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #94a25c;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* The sticky class*/

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---------------------------------------------------Header--------------------------------------------------->
<div class='headBG posRel' id='home'>
  <div class='pTop-4 pLeft-10'>
    <img class='floatLeft roundedBorader' src='https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EaZSuXXXkAAMtJ5?format=jpg&name=360x360' height="150" width="150"/>
    <div class='centerHeadLine pLeft-25'>
      <h1 class='b'>Welcome friends</h1>
      <h5 class='b'><u>The spot where we test some html, css and js</u></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--NAV-->
  <div class="navbar fitWidth" id="navbar">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a class="" href="#news">News</a>
      <a class="" href="#products">Products</a>
      <a class="" href="#services">Services</a>
      <a class="" href="#customers">Customers</a>
      <a class="" href="#community">Community</a>
      <a class="" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">About 
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
     <!-- //TODO: Modals als POP up einbauen, mit jeweiligen content -->
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<!---------------------------------------------------Content-------------------------------------------------->
<div class='contentBody'>
  <!--News-->
   <div class='news' id="news">

      <h1 class='a centerText pTop-5 mTop-5'>News</h1>
      <h5 class='a centerText'>Stay tunned with our News</h5>

    <div class='alignBox'>
      <div class='leftBox50 alignBox roundedBox'> 
        <div class='centerText'>
          <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='rightBox50 alignBox roundedBox'>
        <div class='centerText'>
          <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>        
        </div>        
      </div>  
   </div>
    <div class='alignBox pAll-20' id=''>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <label class='white' for="lname">Newsletter:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  <!--//News-->
  
  <!--Products-->
  <div class='products' id='products'>
    <h1 class='centerText pTop-6 mTop-5'>Products</h1>
    <h5 class='b centerText'>Stay tunned with our products</h5>
    <div class='leftText pAll-20'>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>    
    <div class='pAll-20'>
      <div class='white pBox1 bgLightGreyX'>
        <img class='pTop-5' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'/><br>
        <p>Product #1</p>
      </div>
      <div class='white pBox1 bgLightGreyX'>
        <img class='pTop-5' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'/><br>
        <p>Product #2</p>
      </div>
      <div class='white pBox1 bgLightGreyX'>
        <img class='pTop-5' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'/><br>
        <p>Product #3</p>
      </div>
      <div class='white pBox1 bgLightGreyX'>
        <img class='pTop-5' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'/><br>
        <p class='black'>Product #4</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class='pTop-10 pLR'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus e</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--//Products-->
  <!--Services-->
  <div class='services' id='services'>
    <h1 class='centerText pTop-5 mTop-5'>tile#1</h1>
    <h5 class='b centerText'>Stay tunned with our Services</h5>
    
    <div class='pLeft-5 fitContBoxLeft roundedBox'>
      <img class='floatLeft' src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'/><br>
      <div class='floatLeft pLeft-5'>tile#2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='pRight-5 fitContBoxRight roundedBox'>
      <img class='floatRight' src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'/><br>
      <div class='floatRight pRight-5'>tile#3</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='pLeft-5 fitContBoxLeft roundedBox'>
      <img class='floatLeft' src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'/><br>
      <div class='floatLeft pLeft-5'>tile#4</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='pRight-5 fitContBoxRight roundedBox'>
      <img class='floatRight' src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'/><br>
      <div class='floatRight pRight-5'>tile#5</div>
    </div>
    
    <h4 class='centerText pTop-5'>asdfadsf asdf  asdf asd f asdfvices</h4>
    <div class=''></div>
  </div>
  <!--//Services-->
  <!--Customers-->
  <div class='customers' id='customers'>
    <h1 class='a centerText'>Customers</h1>
    <div class=''></div>
    <div class=''></div>
    <p>jgfjhgfghjf</p>
  </div>
  <!--//Customers-->
  <!--Community-->
  <div class='' id='Community'>
    <h1 class='a centerText'>Community</h1>
    <div class=''></div>
    <div class=''></div>
  </div>
  <!--//Community-->
  <!--Contact-->
  <div class='' id='Contact'>
    <h1 class='a centerText'>Contact</h1>
    <div class=''></div>
    <div class=''></div>
  </div>
  <!--//Contact-->
  <!--About-->
  <div class='aboutUs'>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <!--//About-->
</>
<!---------------------------------------------------Footer--------------------------------------------------->
<div class='footerBox'>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you're changing the behaviour of your navbar to be static or sticky, i.e. removing it from body-height, and instead placing it ontop of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it to JS/JQuery, JQuery in my case. Add this script, you will have more control, and you will be able to make an animation if you change `, 0` to miliseconds. Note tha I'm subtracting navbar height from the container position.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navbar a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - $("#navbar").height()
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

```js
//Sticky-NavBar
window.onscroll = function() {stickyNavBar()};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function stickyNavBar() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navbar a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - $("#navbar").height()
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

```css
/*Base*/
.contentBody{
  background-color: white;
}

/*Sections*/
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#header{}
#news{}
#products{background-color: aqua;}
#services{}
#customers{}
#community{}
#contact{}
#about{}
#footer{}
/*Width Element*/
.fitWidth{
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
.width100{
  width: 100%;
}
.fitContBoxLeft{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.fitContBoxRight{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
/**/


/*Borders*/
.roundedBorader{
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.roundedBox{
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
/*Div*/
.headingBox{
  position: relative
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 268;
}
.news{
  background-color: purple;
}
.products{
  background-color: white;
}
.services{
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.customers{
  background-color: blue;
}
.pBox1{
  float:left;
  width: 24.7%;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.headBottomLine{
  height: 12%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.leftBox50{
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 2px;
}
.rightBox50{
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 2px;
}
.bodyBox{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.aboutUs{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
.footerBox{
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

/*Backgrounds*/
.headBG{
  background-image: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/double-bubble.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

/*Position*/
.bottom0{
  bottom: 0;
}
.posRel{
  position: relative;
}
.posAbs{
  position: absolute;
}

/*Float*/
.floatLeft{
  float: left;
}
.floatRight{
  float: right;
}

/*Alignment*/
.justiText{
  text-align: justify;
}
.rightText{
  text-align: right;
}
.leftText{
  text-align: left;
}
.centerText{
  text-align: center;
}
.alignBox{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/*Padding*/
.pAll-5{
  padding: 5%;
}
.pTop-8{
  padding-top: 8%;
}
.pTop-5{
  padding-top: 5%;
}
.pTop-2{
  padding-top: 2%;
}
.mTop-n3{
  margin-top: -3%;
}
.mTop-5{
  margin-top: auto;
}
.mTop-6{
  margin-top: 6%;
}
.pLine{
  width:100%;
}
.pLR{
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.pBot-12{
  padding-bottom: 12%;
}
.pTop-10{
  padding-top: 10%;
}
.pTop-6{
    padding-top: 6%;
}
.pTop-1{
  padding-top: 2%;
}
.pLeft-30{
  padding-left: 30%;
}
.pLeft-25{
  padding-left: 25%;
}
.pLeft-20{
  padding-left: 20%;
}
.pLeft-10{
  padding-left: 10%;
}
.pLeft-5{
  padding-left: 5%;
}
.pRight-5{
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.pTop-4{
  padding-top: 4%;
}
.pAll-20{
  padding: 20px;
}
.pLTRB{
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.centerHeadLine{
    padding-bottom: 7%;
}

/*Colors*/
.white{
  color: white;
}
.black{
  color: black;
}
.grey{
  color: grey;
}
.lightgrey{
  color: lightgrey;
}
div.c{
  color: lightgrey;
}
div.b{
  color: white;
}
div.a{
  color: black;
}
.bgCol-black{
  background-color: black;
}
.bgCol-grey{
  background-color: grey;
}
.bgCol-purple{
  background-color: #8e42c7;
}
.bgCol-white{
  background-color: white;
}
.bgCol-lightgrey{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.bgCol-limegreen{
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.bgLightGreyX{
  background-color: #d5d2d670;
}

/*Filter styles*/
.saturate { filter: saturate(3); }
.grayscale { filter: grayscale(100%); }
.contrast { filter: contrast(160%); }
.brightness { filter: brightness(0.25); }
.blur { filter: blur(3px); }
.invert { filter: invert(100%); }
.sepia { filter: sepia(100%); }
.huerotate { filter: hue-rotate(180deg); }
.rss.opacity { filter: opacity(50%); }

/*Heading Colors*/
h1.a{
  color: white;
}
h1.b{
  color: black;
}
h5.a{
  color: white;
}
h4.b{
  color: black;
}
h4.a{
  color: white;
}
h5.b{
  color: black;
}

/*Body*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/*NavBar*/
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Nav-Dropdown*/
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #ea8013;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #333;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #94a25c;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* The sticky class*/

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---------------------------------------------------Header--------------------------------------------------->
<div class='headBG posRel' id='home'>
  <div class='pTop-4 pLeft-10'>
    <img class='floatLeft roundedBorader' src='https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EaZSuXXXkAAMtJ5?format=jpg&name=360x360' height="150" width="150"/>
    <div class='centerHeadLine pLeft-25'>
      <h1 class='b'>Welcome friends</h1>
      <h5 class='b'><u>The spot where we test some html, css and js</u></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--NAV-->
  <div class="navbar fitWidth" id="navbar">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a class="" href="#news">News</a>
      <a class="" href="#products">Products</a>
      <a class="" href="#services">Services</a>
      <a class="" href="#customers">Customers</a>
      <a class="" href="#community">Community</a>
      <a class="" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">About 
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
     <!-- //TODO: Modals als POP up einbauen, mit jeweiligen content -->
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<!---------------------------------------------------Content-------------------------------------------------->
<div class='contentBody'>
  <!--News-->
   <div class='news' id="news">

      <h1 class='a centerText pTop-5 mTop-5'>News</h1>
      <h5 class='a centerText'>Stay tunned with our News</h5>

    <div class='alignBox'>
      <div class='leftBox50 alignBox roundedBox'> 
        <div class='centerText'>
          <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='rightBox50 alignBox roundedBox'>
        <div class='centerText'>
          <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>        
        </div>        
      </div>  
   </div>
    <div class='alignBox pAll-20' id=''>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <label class='white' for="lname">Newsletter:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  <!--//News-->
  
  <!--Products-->
  <div class='products' id='products'>
    <h1 class='centerText pTop-6 mTop-5'>Products</h1>
    <h5 class='b centerText'>Stay tunned with our products</h5>
    <div class='leftText pAll-20'>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>    
    <div class='pAll-20'>
      <div class='white pBox1 bgLightGreyX'>
        <img class='pTop-5' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'/><br>
        <p>Product #1</p>
      </div>
      <div class='white pBox1 bgLightGreyX'>
        <img class='pTop-5' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'/><br>
        <p>Product #2</p>
      </div>
      <div class='white pBox1 bgLightGreyX'>
        <img class='pTop-5' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'/><br>
        <p>Product #3</p>
      </div>
      <div class='white pBox1 bgLightGreyX'>
        <img class='pTop-5' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'/><br>
        <p class='black'>Product #4</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class='pTop-10 pLR'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus e</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--//Products-->
  <!--Services-->
  <div class='services' id='services'>
    <h1 class='centerText pTop-5 mTop-5'>tile#1</h1>
    <h5 class='b centerText'>Stay tunned with our Services</h5>
    
    <div class='pLeft-5 fitContBoxLeft roundedBox'>
      <img class='floatLeft' src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'/><br>
      <div class='floatLeft pLeft-5'>tile#2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='pRight-5 fitContBoxRight roundedBox'>
      <img class='floatRight' src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'/><br>
      <div class='floatRight pRight-5'>tile#3</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='pLeft-5 fitContBoxLeft roundedBox'>
      <img class='floatLeft' src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'/><br>
      <div class='floatLeft pLeft-5'>tile#4</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='pRight-5 fitContBoxRight roundedBox'>
      <img class='floatRight' src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'/><br>
      <div class='floatRight pRight-5'>tile#5</div>
    </div>
    
    <h4 class='centerText pTop-5'>asdfadsf asdf  asdf asd f asdfvices</h4>
    <div class=''></div>
  </div>
  <!--//Services-->
  <!--Customers-->
  <div class='customers' id='customers'>
    <h1 class='a centerText'>Customers</h1>
    <div class=''></div>
    <div class=''></div>
    <p>jgfjhgfghjf</p>
  </div>
  <!--//Customers-->
  <!--Community-->
  <div class='' id='Community'>
    <h1 class='a centerText'>Community</h1>
    <div class=''></div>
    <div class=''></div>
  </div>
  <!--//Community-->
  <!--Contact-->
  <div class='' id='Contact'>
    <h1 class='a centerText'>Contact</h1>
    <div class=''></div>
    <div class=''></div>
  </div>
  <!--//Contact-->
  <!--About-->
  <div class='aboutUs'>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <!--//About-->
</>
<!---------------------------------------------------Footer--------------------------------------------------->
<div class='footerBox'>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this :)

Comment: Okay! Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When you transform an element with the `position: fixed;`, this element stop taking place. So you need to compensate the lack of height that your navbar aren't taking anymore.

Comment: Thanks. So it must be possible to do this with the js function before navigate to the target position,right? Can i go like this: 1.)cut element 2.)replace the lost space 3.)scroll to position?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with your JS function.
But you need to have either :
- another element replacing your navbar with the same dimensions
- or one existing element near your navbar that grows of the size of the missing navbar